# How to print an interval of a 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

So i have my 2D array initialized with data from a file and i was wondering if it's possible to System.out.print just this interval.

```
public static void OptionUn (String[][] TableauLectureFichier) {

    Scanner rDates = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("ENTER YOUR INTERVAL HERE IN THE FOLLOWING ORDER DAY1 MONTH1 DAY2 MONTH2");

    String Intervale = rDates.nextLine();

    String[] TabChaine = Intervale.split(" ");
    int[] tIntervale = new int[4];

    for (int i = 0; i <TabChaine.length; i++) {            
        tIntervale[i] = Integer.parseInt(TabChaine[i]);
    }

    int j1 = tIntervale[0],
        j2 = tIntervale[2],
        m1 = tIntervale[1],
        m2 = tIntervale[3];
}
```

My array basicly contains Temperature, each row is a temperature of a certain date, its all ordered for january 1st to december 31st. And my question is how can I only System.out.print the temperatures between the dates the USER enters. For exemple between January 1st and February first (1 1 1 2).

So the array looks as follow. It's an irregular 2D array

```
String[][] TableauLectureFichier = new String[12][];
        TableauLectureFichier[1] = new String[31];
        TableauLectureFichier[2] = new String[LeapYear];
        TableauLectureFichier[3] = new String[31];
        TableauLectureFichier[4] = new String[30];
        TableauLectureFichier[5] = new String[31];
        TableauLectureFichier[6] = new String[30];
        TableauLectureFichier[7] = new String[31];
        TableauLectureFichier[8] = new String[31];
        TableauLectureFichier[9] = new String[30];
        TableauLectureFichier[10] = new String[31];
        TableauLectureFichier[11] = new String[30];
        TableauLectureFichier[12] = new String[31];
```

Where LeapYear is a method that calculates if february has 28 or 29 days

Comment: What does the array `TableauLectureFichier` contain?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you asking how to print the elements of the integer array you have? Or are you planning on using the ints j1, j2, m1 and m2 to index into the array that you are receving in the method head?

Comment: More details about what you are trying to do, what the problem you are facing is, and what you have tried so far will help you get a better answer faster

Comment: you need to specify what you mean with "print" and what output do you want. java provides you with many options to format strings.

Comment: Still not clear what the data looks like. Is it something like `String TableauLectureFichier[365][31]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to print from the two dimensional array passed to the function, and use the input from the user to print a selected range from the passed array?

Your issue must be, that simply doing two nested loops, will not solve this for you. Instead, you want to increment a calendar from the "start month" and "start day" to the "end month" and "end day".

**Update**

Ok, since you do not want to use a Calendar for this, you can do this by just iterating through the 2d array with a bit of logic. I will assume the the length of the second dimension of the array will vary depending on what month we are in. Meaning, that the code that supplies the data, will only have one entry for each valid day.

So, if the data is recorded on a leap year, the array dimension for February will simply be of the length 29. (`TableauLectureFichier[1].length == 29`)

Then you can do it with the following:

```
public static void OptionUn (String[][] TableauLectureFichier) {

    Scanner rDates = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("ENTER YOUR INTERVAL HERE IN THE FOLLOWING ORDER DAY1 MONTH1 DAY2 MONTH2");

    String Intervale = rDates.nextLine();

    String[] TabChaine = Intervale.split(" ");
    int[] tIntervale = new int[4];

    for (int i = 0; i <TabChaine.length; i++) {            
        tIntervale[i] = Integer.parseInt(TabChaine[i]);
    }

    int j1 = tIntervale[0],
        j2 = tIntervale[2],
        m1 = tIntervale[1],
        m2 = tIntervale[3];

    // Loop through all the months specified, taking care to convert from base 1 
    // to base 0
    for (int month = m1 - 1; month < m2; month++) {
        // Assume that we will start at the first day of a month
        int day = 0;

        // However, if the current month is the first, start from the day specified as j1 
        // instead, and convert to base 0 so that we can use it to index into the array
        if (month == m1) {
            day = j1 - 1;
        }

        // Assume that we will run till the end of this month, or in this case to the end
        // of the array for the current month
        int endDay = TableauLectureFichier[month].length;

        // If the current month is the last month, only run to specified end day
        if (month == m2) {
            endDay = j2;
        }

        // Now run from the start day to the end day in the current month, paying 
        // attention to that endDay is still base 1
        for (; day < endDay; day++) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Month: %d, day: %d, value %s",
                month, 
                day, 
                TableauLectureFichier[month][day]));
        }

        // At this point we will step into the next month
    }
}
```

I have not added bounds checking to the `month` or 'day' variables. So if you are handing this in to anyone - please add bounds checking before you use the variables in the array.

Comment: Yes I just realized I forgot to specify the year, but my program reads all the data off a file so it depends on what file the user will enter and what year is that file related so i have to make it work for leap years aswell. The thing is, it's my school project and we never used Calenders before, therefore I can't use that as a way to print that part of the 2D Array. This is why I was wondering if there is any loop other than that that is possible to just print a part of the array Between the Day/Month of beginning and Day/month of end the user enters.

Comment: I think I understand your request now. Please check the code above - and test if this is working out for you.

Comment: Yes I had a hard time trying to figure out the right loops. This one works perfectly fine. Tank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

public static void OptionUn (String[][] TableauLectureFichier) {

```
Scanner rDates = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("ENTER YOUR INTERVAL HERE IN THE FOLLOWING ORDER DAY1 MONTH1 DAY2 MONTH2");

String Intervale = rDates.nextLine();

String[] TabChaine = Intervale.split(" ");
int[] tIntervale = new int[4];

for (int i = 0; i <TabChaine.length; i++) {            
    tIntervale[i] = Integer.parseInt(TabChaine[i]);
}

int j1 = tIntervale[0],
    j2 = tIntervale[2],
    m1 = tIntervale[1],
    m2 = tIntervale[3];


for(int i=m1+1; i < m2; i++) {
    for(int j=j1+1; j < j2; j++) {
         System.out.printf("Temperature on day %d and month %d: %s", j, i,  TableauLectureFichier[i][j]);
    }
}
```

}